# How to install and test Adobe Commerce B2B Shared Catalog?

Tags: magento2, b2b, sharedcatalog

After installing Magento 2.4.3 + B2B + SampleData, I wasn't able to test the Shared Catalog feature.

[image: Magento 2.4.3 + B2B + SampleData]

What's the process to install it and test it properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set up Magento B2B you might have Adobe Commerce installed, then you might be able to see the admin option running these commands below.

```
composer require magento/extension-b2b
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
bin/magento cache:clean
```

Running this command below you will make all the message queues running in the background, which makes your store **show products in the frontend**.

```
bin/magento queue:consumers:list | xargs -I % sh -c 'bin/magento queue:consumers:start % &'
```

#### Enable B2B features in Magento Admin

After installing the B2B for the Adobe Commerce extension and starting message consumers (if you want to enable the Shared Catalog module), you must also enable B2B modules in Magento Admin.

Enable it in the Magento Admin via **Stores > Settings > Configuration > General > B2B Features**.

[image: Enable Adobe Commerce B2B features in Magento Admin]