# Magento 2.4.3 not showing products and error to reindex Catalog Search

Tags: magento2, catalog, installation, reindex, elasticsearch

I just installed an Adobe Commerce 2.4.3 B2B + SampleData, but when I open my catalogue of products in the frontend I don't see products in the list, even seeing products in the backend, I thought it would be an issue caused by the reindex, during the reindex I had this issue below.

```
Design Config Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Customer Grid index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Category Products index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Categories index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Rule Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product EAV index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Inventory index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Product Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Stock index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Product Permissions index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product/Target Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:03
Target Rule/Product index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Catalog Category Permissions index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
Product Price index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:01
Catalog Search index process unknown error:
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"request [/magento2_product_1_v2/document/_mapping] contains unrecognized parameter: [include_type_name]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"request [/magento2_product_1_v2/document/_mapping] contains unrecognized parameter: [include_type_name]"},"status":400}
Sales Rule index has been rebuilt successfully in 00:00:00
```

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're installing a clean installation, it's not related to 3º party code, it's probably related to your server, check the ElasticSearch installed via this command below.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200'
```

[image: ElasticSearch - Adobe Commerce 2.4.3]

The versions supported are 5, 6 and 7 (recommended).

[image: ElasticSearch compatibility - Adobe Commerce 2.4.3]

These are the recommended versions.

[image: Magento 2 - ElasticSearch recommended versions]

After changing your current ElasticSearch, it's required to run:

```
bin/magento index:reset
bin/magento index:reindex
```

### Adobe Commerce B2B

As you mentioned Magento B2B, I recommend disabling **Shared Catalog** and test it again.

[image: Magento 2 Shared Catalog not working]

In case it started to work, I recommend checking this post below to see how you can use the queue system to make **Shared Catalog** work properly.

[How to use **Shared Catalog** in Adobe Commerce B2B?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/344541/16416)